# How to write triplets in 4/4 time without using a 3 on top of the notes all the time

Tags: sheet-music

I am writing a song and in cubase (DAW) the score I get looks this. [image]

Is there really no better way to write this without using a 3 on top of each beat? Is there something I could put at the top of the piece since the whole song is a shuffle like this?

Comment: What is your intention with this - is the rhythm supposed to be a slow rock, shuffle, triplet swing, or lighter-than-triplet swing?

Comment: If you look at the score for “Bolero” by Ravel, you’ll see it’s just packed with triplets.

Comment: Or is your piece more in the classical music, soundtrack, or concert band vein? In those cases, swing indications are often inappropriate.

Comment: First movement of the Moonlight Sonata?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Good example - Most printings I've seen of the Moonlight have 3's over the triplets in the first measure, but then just leave the rest unmarked.  It's pretty clearly implied that the same rhythm continues for the whole piece.  This method of marking is pretty commonly used when the base part is just repeating a triplet pattern the whole time.  Possibly less so in the case of a shuffle where it's 2-1, 2-1, 2-1, 2-1 instead of the 1-1-1, 1-1-1, 1-1-1, 1-1-1 pattern of the Moonlight et al.

Comment: I know that Logic Pro has a "swing" option, which automatically turns what are notated as eighth note rhythms in the score editor into swung triplets. It even lets users adjust the strength of the swing, making the rhythm anything from a slightly late eighth note to a hard, traditional triplet swing. Perhaps Cubase has something similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the same as the keyword "shuffle", but wouldn't the below example get your intention across?

[image]

Edit: Another option is to indicate the triples for the first bar, then use the word 'simile' to show the idea is to continue this for the reminder of the piece:

[image]

https://musicterms.artopium.com/s/Simile.htm

> A directive to perform the indicated passage of a composition in a
>   similar manner as the previous passage; similarly. One common use is
>   to designate the continuation of the use of an articulation without
>   repeating the articulation symbol. Often abbreviated as
>   sim. . similarly; i.e., continue applying the preceding directive,
>   whatever it was, to the following passageto continue to do something
>   in the same way it was formerly notated such as pedaling or staccatos

Comment: Mathematically, perhaps.  But Shuffle and Swing are quite distinct feels.  Difficult to describe in words, easy to hear.

Comment: @ Laurence. If the track is swing @ 100% then it is a shuffle isn't it?

Comment: @MeanGreen thanks for this answer, but if I do use the "swing" bit at the top of my score I would still need to notate the triplets at the end of the first bar right?

Comment: I don't think so. As other answers have mentioned, the number of notes in each bar (but also the fact you combined the last notes of the first bar into a group of 3) should be indication enough, though not extremely helpful to future readers. I've added another image as an alternative solution: the simile instruction.

Comment: @armani: if you have an actual triplet in addition to the swinging eights, it's best to write it as a triplet. Otherwise it will be very confusing to read, because without the "3" it will look like its total time value is one and a half quarter-notes.

Answer (score 14):

You'll see it done in all of these ways.   12/8 is the obvious answer.   Straight 8s plus a 'Shuffle' instruction is useful if you're writing into a notation program like Sibelius - but you have to make sure 'Shuffle' IS defined in the Playback Dictionary.  The third way will be understood by live musicians, but will confuse computer playback.

I recommend 12/8.  Using 12/8 is completely clear and unambiguous both to humans and computers.

There's also the possibiity that you're playing with a Swing feel (not precise triplets), and triplets are Cubase's best guess.   If this is the case, write straight 8's and 'Swing'.

[image]

Comment: We see 'swing' far more than 'shuffle'. Unless 'shuffle is what they define it as in Sibelius, et al. Or do I read the wrong music? And the last one seems too far away from swing/shuffle at 75/25%. 12/8 is what came to mind when the question was read. +1.

Comment: 12/8 is often very hard to read if the rhythms are at all complicated.

Comment: Do you assume the OP means the song to be a shuffle? I think it's not clear at all what the intended rhythmic feeling or message to musicians is, and the notation shown is just a guess made by the software. Cubase won't be able to tell if your MIDI notes are trying to represent swing or shuffle or something. It's just a dumb machine.

Comment: @Tim When reading music, I always assumed "shuffle" to be roughly equivalent to "swing", i.e. implying an uneven eighth-note division inside the beat. Was I off the mark the whole time? I thought the two were nearly identical (shuffle carrying stylistically different implications than swing, but nonetheless...)? (Or perhaps this is one of those terms that gets a little twist when it crosses the Atlantic, if you catch my drift...)

Comment: @ Laurence, I have swing set at 100% in cubase and I realize that this could confuse the score plugin but among the swung notes there are lots of actual triplets and since the swing is set to 100% there is no doubt that it is a shuffle. Isn't your second example kind of the same as Meangreens? If so both are ideal since I only would need to write one word at the top of the score which would save me writing all those "3"s

Answer (score 8):

You might be able to use implicit tuplets if the groupings stay consistent throughout a significant section of the piece. Notate the first couple measures explicitly and let the musician figure it out from there (most moderately skilled musicians should be able to handle this). (Optionally, to make it more clear, you may want to add 'simile' or 'sim.' after the last explicitly marked tuple.) Again, this should only be used in long passages (preferably the entire piece) with consistent rhythmic groupings and patterns. Also, if the moderately skilled musician mentioned above *can't* figure it out, this probably isn't the best solution!

Here are a couple examples:

---

> In Chopin's Fantasie Impromptu only the first sextuplet is notated and
>   the rest are implied with slur markings, a repeated structural pattern
>   and the fact that there are simply too many notes squeezed in. Also note that the melody (not shown) is written in non tuplets, making writing this in 12/8 impractical.
>
> [image: Fantasie Impromptu Snippet]

---

> In Schubert's Impromptu Op. 90 No. 3 we are not given any tuplet
>   notation at all. Instead, the groupings are inferred by the fact that
>   there are 6 notes when there should clearly only be 4.
>
> [image: Schubert Impromptu Snippet]

---

> **EDIT:** And, of course, Moonlight Sonata, as mentioned in the OP comments. :)
>
> [image: Moonlight Sonata]

Comment: The melody of that Chopin piece is 8 notes for every 6 in the bass.  To make those all line up on the beats without using tuplets would be insane.  Also, playing that piece with mathematical precision would sound very robotic and wholly unsatisfying.  You shouldn't be thinking about exactly where every note lies in the measure, but more about the overall flow they have.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Aligning the 8 over 6 polyrhythm (or rather, 4 over 3, twice) isn't terribly difficult at slower speeds. Fantasie Impromptu, however, is just about as far from "slower speeds" as you can get! Chopin's works are full of odd tuples (septets, octets, etc.), complicated polyrhythms (like 8 over 3) and out-of-time runs (essentially 10 - 30 note "tuplets"). All of these techniques intentionally break away from the precise timing found in classical and baroque styles and require a mental separation from the pulse, driving the music by feeling and emotion instead of technical precision.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman So yes, while you could theoretically pick them apart mathematically, doing so would effectively ruin the piece, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it in 12/8, it's easier to write. And to read. And it will be interpreted the same.